# Invalid Identifier in Subquery

Tags: sql

I am working on below query

```
SELECT auth_number,
  status
FROM auth_services_cnv auth
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) b
    FROM auth_services_cnv
    WHERE status   ='D'
    AND auth_number=auth.auth_number
    GROUP BY auth_number
    ) a1 ,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) c
    FROM auth_services_cnv
    WHERE 1        =1
    AND auth_number=auth.auth_number
    GROUP BY auth_number
    ) a2
  WHERE a1.b=a2.c
  );
```

/

I am getting below error

ORA-00904: "AUTH"."AUTH_NUMBER": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 42 Column: 21

---

Actually my requirement is like this

auth_number            status
1                       D
1                       P
1                       D
1                       D
2                       D
2                       D
2                       D

I need to select auth_number which is having status as all 'D'.
That means I need to select auth_number with 2.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

--
Sandhya

Comment: What is the point of having `1=1` ?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty A lot of generated sql starts or ends the where clause with (1=1). It allows you to not think about whether you need to include a leading or trailing `and`, you just always include the `and`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this instead:

```
SELECT  auth_number,
        status
FROM auth_services_cnv
WHERE auth_number NOT IN (SELECT auth_number
                          FROM auth_services_cnv
                          WHERE Status <> 'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an oracle only solution

```
SELECT auth_number
FROM auth_services_cnv 
MINUS
SELECT auth_number
FROM auth_services_cnv 
WHERE Status <> 'D'
```